# Why does this plain JavaScript work and it's equivalent jQuery fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I found a javascript that deals with HTML5 File Reader API. It's written in pure javascript, I am in the process of converting it to a jQuery script. But am getting stuck at this point.

This works:

```
document.getElementById('drop-area').addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.dataTransfer.files); // outputs the right stuff
}, false);
```

This fails:

```
$('#drop-area').on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.dataTransfer.files); // ERROR: e.dataTransfer is undefined 
});
```

What is a solution to this problem?

Comment: If you have equivalent codes, why not just use the pure JS because it is faster?

Comment: @Markasoftware the rest of my app is using jQuery I rather have a uniform code base. Also parts of this script involve custom DOM manipulation which is much cleaner/painless to do with jQuery of course.

Comment: @TK123 If you want a uniform codebase, just use plain JavaScript. After all, even the `+` operator is plain JavaScript, so just by using jQuery you're being inconsistent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery does not normalize the `dataTransfer` event property, to access it you'll have to go through the original event.

```
console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
```

You can also set it so that `dataTransfer` is added to the jQuery event object by the following.

```
jQuery.event.props.push( "dataTransfer" );
```